# Извлечь содержимое тега href из строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка в переменной $text:

```
<div class="feed-task-info-block"> <div class="feed-task-info-label">Задача<div class="feed-task-info-label-icon"></div></div> <div class="feed-task-info-text"> <div class="feed-task-info-text-item"> <span class="feed-task-info-text-title">Сергей изменил статус задачи <a href="/company/personal/user/512/tasks/task/view/274664/" onclick="if (taskIFramePopup.isLeftClick(event)) {taskIFramePopup.view(274664); return false;}">test</a></span> </div><div class="feed-task-info-text-item"> <span class="feed-task-info-text-title">Задача закрыта</span> </div> <div class="feed-task-info-text-item"> <span class="feed-task-info-text-title">Ответственный:</span><span class="feed-task-info-text-cont"><a id="tasks-user-tooltip-5c17bd6526296" href="/company/personal/user/1433/">Сергей</a></span> </div> </div> <script> BX.tooltip(1433, 'tasks-user-tooltip-5c17bd6526296', ''); </script> </div>
```

Извлекаю содержимое тегов href:

```
preg_match('/^<a.*?href=(["\'])(.*?)\1.*$/', $text, $out);
print_r($out);
```

получаю:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Почему массив пустой?

Comment: В строке нет слова watch и даже ссылки с GET

Comment: Не понял. В по регулярному выражению ссылка должна начинаться с `watch`, но в переменной `$text` нет ни одной такой ссылки.

Comment: [вероятно ответ здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Извиняюсь, уже втыкаю) поправил, но все-равно результат тот же

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/href="([^\"]+)"/', $text, $out);
```

Comment: `preg_match_all('/href="(.*?)"/', $str, $matches);`